# Why does the "width: auto" property have no effect on the Angular mat-table element?

Tags: css, html-table, width, angular9, mat-table

I'm using Angular 9.  I have a simple mat-table with three columns ...

```
<mat-table *ngIf="!isMobile" #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="time">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Time </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let article_stat">{{ getTime(article_stat) }} m</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="score">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> score </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let article_stat">
        {{ getscore(article_stat) }} ({{ getWeightedscore(article_stat) }}) 
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="article">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Article </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let article_stat">
        <a href='{{ article_stat.article.path }}'>{{ article_stat.article.title }}</a>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="getRowClass(row)"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Below is my simple CSS for the component.  There is no CSS at the app component level ...

```
.mat-table {
    width: auto;
}

.rising {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

However, when my table is rendered, it is taking up 100% of the screen, despite the fact the data in each column does not occupy that much space.  If I change the width to a fixed pixel width, (e.g. "200px"), browsers respect the wdith.  Why isn't "width: auto" working and how do I style my mat-table such that it only takes up as much space as the data within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the documentation from Angular concerning "mat-table".

In the examples given they are using the table element with "mat-table" included in the beginning table tag:

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width: auto;
}
```

I have tested the css of `width: auto;` and it is working as expected - This was pulled straight from the Angular [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) and tested in stackbliz. You can view my working test [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlvgkf?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html).

Edit:
To be more clear, at the bottom of the documentation page listed above there is a note for using `Tables with display: flex` (`<mat-table>` instead of `<table mat-table>`).

> Note that this approach means you cannot include certain native-table
> features such colspan/rowspan or have columns that resize themselves
> based on their content.

Comment: Thanks but your example is not quite what I have.  You are using the "mat-table", "mat-cell", and "mat-row" classes, but I'm using those as tags (elements).

Comment: Oh, I'm a little slow.  You meant to say I should be using the classes instead of the tags?

Comment: I added an edit to my post to be more clear - You cannot have columns that resize themselves based on the content when using <mat-table> instead of <table mat-table>.